# flutter: FadeInImage.assetNetwork: how to add request header like access token

Tags: image, security, flutter

I'm using FadeInImage.assetNetwork display images with a place holder, which works fine for public images. However, I need to use access headers while getting some images. How to achieve that as FadeInImage takes string as the ImageProvider param. Is there any similar widget available to add request parameter?

Comment: see `NetworkImage` class - it has `headers` property

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can directly use FadeInImage and pass a NetworkImage as an ImageProvider(and its headers).

```
FadeInImage(
    placeholder: AssetImage("images/placeholder.jpg"),
    image: NetworkImage(
        "https://flutter.io/images/catalog-widget-placeholder.png",
        headers: {"header": "value"}),
  )
);
```